# Can't run gulp - Unexpected token ]

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I want to create an application with angular2, and I've downloaded the angular2 folder structure from [here](https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/angular-2-beta-boilerplate).
I've also installed globally gulp in my system with `npm install gulp –g`, now when I try to run gulp with the command `gulp` I get this error:

```
undefined:14
  ]
  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Function.createProject (/home/pc02/Desktop/myapp/angular-2-beta-boilerplate/node_modules/gulp-typescript/release/main.js:195:40)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pc02/Desktop/myapp/angular-2-beta-boilerplate/gulpfile.js:26:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
```

I'm working on Ubuntu

Comment: have you installed the local dependencies needed for the project ? ie `npm install`

Comment: @swapnesh yes I have

Comment: I recommend submitting an issue on that Github repo.

Comment: When you run `gulp -v` does it return any version info?

Comment: I reinstalled gulp and few other things, now everything works perfectly. By the way gulp -v returned the version, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Ubuntu, you should run: `sudo npm install gulp -g`. It won't get installed properly without the "sudo".